# Display video stream on google cardboard

Tags: android, opengl-es, google-cardboard

When I am using SurfaceView to display video stream it is working perfectly. But I want to display video on google cardboard but I got this error:

```
W/GLConsumer: [unnamed-22692-3] bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x500
```

Same to this issue: [Display a gstreamer video feed into Google Cardboard SurfaceTexture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602491/display-a-gstreamer-video-feed-into-google-cardboard-surfacetexture)